# Pass data to two views from table

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, segue

I have a table which is connected to a MySQL database, the table populates and when a row is selected relevant data is displayed in a detail view, I also have another view (Map2View) which is connected to the detail view and I want the same data to be passed to it aswell. Im using this code, but the Map2view is not receiving it, labels Im trying to update are blank and if I connect Map2View to the table view they update. What is the correct way of doing this or can this be done differently.

TableView segue

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"pushRoutesDetailView"])
    {
        NSIndexPath * indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        Route * object = [routesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [[segue destinationViewController] getRoute:object];
    }
    else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"pushMap2View"]) {
        Map2ViewController *map2VC = (Map2ViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        NSIndexPath * indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        Route * object = [routesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [map2VC getRoute:object];
    }
}
```

Comment: You said that your Map2View is connected to the detail view, but it looks like from the code you posted, that you have it connected to your table view with a segue. Is the else-if clause ever executed?

Comment: Opss I see my mistake, I was meant to do a segue from the detail view to the map view with the same 'getRoute:object'